# Ruby2.3; refactor each_with_object

Tags: ruby

I'd love to do some refactoring code below

```
p line_item_body_elements #=> ['product', 'total', 'subtotal', 'net']  
body = line_item_body_elements.each_with_object([]) do |element, _body|
  _body << send("fetch_invoice_#{element}") if element == 'products'
  _body << send("fetch_invoice_#{element}_amount") unless element == 'products'
end
body
```

**UPDATE**

**What I'd love to accomplish is**

1. iterating over the array (`line_item_body_elements`)
2. call the method based on each element's name
3. the each methods returns back values
4. store them into array
5. concatenate the array to `body`
6. return `body`

Any will be really appreciated.

Comment: What are you iterating over? What are you trying to accomplish? Sorry can't help if I can't understand the problem.

Comment: @Joel_Blum I updated.

Comment: Is `line_item_body_elements` dynamic or are the elements always the same?

Comment: @Stefan It's dynamic.

Comment: How many different elements are there? Just the 4 in the example?

Comment: It depends. For elements are just an example.

Comment: Well, you are calling methods based on the elements, so these methods have to exist, i.e. `fetch_invoice_product`, `fetch_invoice_total_amount` etc.

Comment: If your code works then [so] is the wrong site, you want [codereview.se].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
body = line_item_body_elements.map do |element|
  send("fetch_invoice_#{element}#{'_amount' unless element == 'products'}")
end
```

Comment: The answer above is still _perfectly valid_. It satisfies _all the 6 conditions you’ve stated_.

Comment: You could prepend a `body =` to make it equivalent.